# Creating a loop without writing each equation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave

At the moment if I want to add or take away another `eq#` I also have to adjust the variables in `sig_min_len` and the `weave` variable.

```
fs=60000
t=linspace(0,2*pi,fs); %creates same size time 
freq=100;
for phase=1:360
    phase
    eq1=sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase));
    eq2=sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase+1));
    eq3=sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase+2));
    eq4=sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase+3));
    sig_min_len = min([ length(eq1), length(eq2)  , length(eq3), length(eq4)]); %get min length
    weave=reshape([[eq1(1:sig_min_len)];[eq2(1:sig_min_len)];[eq3(1:sig_min_len)];[eq4(1:sig_min_len)]],1,[])'; %interweave to row vectors into one col vector
end
```

1. Is there a way to make a loop just using one equation `eq1=sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase));`  and have the phase increment while also 
   adjusting the variable `sig_min_len` and the variable `weave` based on how many `phase's` I loop through?
2. Is there a way to make a loop for the variable `sig_min_len` so I don't have to write out each  `length(eq#)`?
   Is there a way to make a loop for the variable `weave` so I don't have to write out each `eq#(1:sig_min_len)`?

PS: I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which works like matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the structure of your `eq#` is almost identical except they differ by just one, this makes perfect case for a `for` loop. The solution to your second problem is to use a cell array to take advantage of its indexing flexibility. Concatenation of all the members of the cell array is achieved by using brackets.  P.S. I'm doing this in MATLAB. I assume it's working almost the same as Octave.

```
fs=60000
t=linspace(0,2*pi,fs);
freq=100;
for phase=1:360
    phase
    for ii = 1:4
        eq{ii} = sin(freq*t+deg2rad(phase+ii-1));
        sig_min_len = min(length(eq{ii}), length(eq{ii-1*(ii~=1)}))
    end
    weave=[eq{:}].';
end
```

The expression `min(length(eq{ii}), length(eq{ii-1*(ii~=1)}))` evaluates to `min(length(eq{1}), length(eq{1)}))` when `ii == 1`. It's much more succinct than an equivalent `if` statement that would like this:

```
if ii = 1
    sig_min_len = length(eq{ii})
else
    sig_min_len = min(length(eq{ii}), length(eq{ii-1}))
end
```